# QGIS Symbol Categorisation

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# get unique values for 'severity' field
fni = layer.fieldNameIndex('severity')
unique_vals = layer.dataProvider().uniqueValues(fni)

# define categories to use in symbology
categories = []

for val in unique_vals:
    # initialise the default symbol for this geometry type
    symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())

    # configure a symbol layer
    layer_style = {}
    layer_style['color'] = '%d, %d, %d' % (randrange(0,256),randrange(0,256),randrange(0,256))

    layer_style['outline'] = '#000000'
    symbol_layer = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayerV2.create(layer_style)

    # replace default symbol layer with the configured one
    if symbol_layer is not None:
        symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)
    else:
        print "success"

    # create renderer object
    category = QgsRendererCategoryV2(val, symbol, str(val))
    # entry for the list of category items
    categories.append(category)

 # create renderer object
 renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2('severity', categories)

# assign the created renderer to the layer
if renderer is not None:
    layer.setRendererV2(renderer)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

I have used [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/175114/75899), and copied the code above in to the python console. It appears to work fine, as I end up with the correct number of categories, i.e. 1 for every unique value in my chosen attribute, however after `categories.append(category)` it prints out `False` for every iteration of the loop. End result is fine though, so would anyone be able to explain why it's printing out `False`?

I thought it might have been `if symbol_layer is not None:` etc. but I added an `else: print "success"` and it's not doing that so doesn't look like that's the issue. Like I said, it does work but I'm curious

perhaps worth mentioning the layer I'm using is from a postgres database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after adding some `print` statements after each line I managed to work out that it's `symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)`:

```
bool QgsSymbolV2::changeSymbolLayer( int index, QgsSymbolLayerV2* layer )
{
   QgsSymbolLayerV2* oldLayer = mLayers.value( index );

   if ( oldLayer == layer )
      return false;

   if ( !layer || !layer->isCompatibleWithSymbol( this ) )
      return false;

   delete oldLayer; // first delete the original layer
   mLayers[index] = layer; // set new layer
   return true;
}
```

[link](http://qgis.org/api/qgssymbolv2_8cpp_source.html) (line 429)

the layer is valid and since everything else works it must be `if (oldLayer == layer)` that's returning `False`. Also I only have 1 layer open