# PyQGIS - categorized renderer classification - create category with 'no value' or 'any other value'

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, qgis-2, categorized-renderer

The code snipped mentioned in [Automatic pyqgis categorized renderer classification](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226642/automatic-pyqgis-categorized-renderer-classification) and [Apply symbol to each feature (Categorized symbol)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175068/apply-symbol-to-each-feature-categorized-symbol/175114#175114) automatically create categorized renderers and determine categories using PyQGIS.

I (using QGIS 2.18.18 LTR) have a layer with `uniqueValues` for a field `pre_cluster_id` like `[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, NULL]` for which the above referred to approaches correctly create a category with value `0` and Legend `0`, but *incorrectly* (from my understanding) create a category with value `0` and legend `NULL` hiding the first one, screenshot:

[image]

Created with the `Classify` Button, there is a category with no value, covering all except `[0, ..., 9]` (including `NULL`):

[image]

Hence, **question**: Using PyQGIS, how can I create a `QgsRendererCategoryV2()` with *no value*, i.e. *all other values* (or a category for `NULL` value, respectively)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NULL` in the `uniqueValues` is of type `QPyNullVariant` (cp. https://nathanw.net/2013/08/31/qgis-2-0-dealing-with-null-values-in-pyqgis/) and a category created as

```
QgsRendererCategoryV2(NULL, mysymbol, 'legend_text')
```

does not create a category with *no value*, but with value `0`. For a category with *no value* it needs to be created as

```
QgsRendererCategoryV2(None, mysymbol, 'legend_text')
```

Therefore, a slight alteration in the codes mentioned in my question solves this issue:

```
[...]
# create renderer object
if unique_value == NULL:
    category = QgsRendererCategoryV2(None, symbol, 'any other values')
else:
    category = QgsRendererCategoryV2(cl_no, symbol, str(cl_no))
# entry for the list of category items
categories.append(category)
[...]
```

But, to be honest, this is only half the answer. I could not find out how to explicitly create a category for the `NULL` values.