# Update symbology when add feature QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology, update, qgis-expression

I'm working in QGIS and I have a virtual layer with lines geometry and categorized symbology by field "name". When I have a new name category I have to do the classify to get the new name in the list of values. I'm looking for a way to do it automatically, that's means, when a new name category it's added to the layer, it's also automatically added in symbology. The symbol it's defined as random colors, so it can be a random line color.

Comment: Perhaps this post would help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226642/automatic-pyqgis-categorized-renderer-classification